# Collective.Uploadify Returns Error 500 After Committing Upload

Tags: jquery, plone, uploadify

After an upgrade and migration from a Plone 4.1.1 installation to Plone 4.2.1, the collective.uploadify egg no longer functions.  From the users prospective, the user can browse to one or more files as before, and files appear to upload (evidenced by advancement of progress bars), however all uploads terminate with "HTTP Error 500".

Both collective.uploadify-1.0 and collective.uploadify-1.1 reproduce this behavior.

**The following error is shown in the client instance log:**

```
------
2012-10-22T19:50:34 INFO collective.uploadify uploading file: filename=myfile.pdf, content_type=application/pdf
------
2012-10-22-T19:50:34 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1350953434.830.935215558164 http://www.example.com/site/@@upload_file
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module collective.uploadify.browser.upload, line 130, in __call__
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 7 argument (4 given)
```

**The following error is shown in the client Z2 Log:**

```
192.168.1.1 - Anonymous [22/Oct/2012:19:59:04 - 0500] "POST /https://localhost/VirtualHostBase/https/www.example.com:443/VirtualHostRoot/mount/site/@upload_file HTTP/1.1" 500 4013 "https://www.example.com/mount/site/@@upload" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
```

Plone runs on RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.5 in private IP space, behind a second RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.5 using Apache configured with Proxy Balancer directives pointing to a RewriteRule.  Plone Site uses ZODB mount points for each distinct site.

The functionality works in the original installation, which has been preserved.   However, this egg no longer works on either the migrated site nor a fresh installation.

Any suggestions on how to resolve or obtain additional troubleshooting details is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Reading between the lines of the source code, it looks as if something registered a `IFileFactory` factory that expects 3 additional arguments, which is a total violation of that interface. Does `collective.uploadify` work in a *new, clean* Plone 4.2 installation?

Comment: No, it did not.  in the clean install, colective.uploadify installs version 1.1.  Therefore, i pinned the version to 1.0 (as existed in the original, functional installation) however, the observations are identical.

How can i go about determining which arguments it is expecting?

Comment: Ah, I assumed the traceback was for 1.1. Could you clarify? Is it 1.1 or 1.0 that produced the traceback you posted? If 1.1, you'll need to find what IFileFactory utilities have been registered (grep through the parts/omelette/ directories probably) to find the culprit. If this breaks in 4.2 as well, something local is b0rken because I see no reports elsewhere that the product doesn't work on 4.2.

Comment: The traceback was in fact for 1.1.  I didn't have much luck searching for more details, either.  In fact, the only reference i could find was this post from earlier this year, which sounds like the same problem:

http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/raptus-article-upload-td7531656.html

I will follow your recommendations and see what comes up!